# minted + escapeinside: how to feed the result of the escape into the lexer?

Tags: minted

The result of an `escapeinside` in `minted` is typeset as-is, and not fed into the lexer. This is by design, as I understand. How can I change `minted`'s behavior so that the result of the `escapeinside` is lexed together with the rest of the code?

In other words, how can I generate source code dynamically and feed it into the lexer?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\something}{bbb}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{mask}
aaa|\something|aaa
aaabbbaaa
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

generates two different lines, whereas I would like it to generate twice exactly the same line:

[image]

From the above code (first line), `minted` generates the `fancyvrb` line

```
\PYG{n+nt}{aaa}\PYG{esc}{\something}\PYG{n+nt}{aaa}
```

whereas what I want is the `\something` command *inside* the `\PYG` call, something like

```
\PYG{n+na}{aaa\something{}aaa}
```